# Ошибки при выполнении post-запроса, в чем причина?

Tags: php

Есть форма:

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
    <input type="text" name="query" id="documentNumber" oninput="identifyType(this.value)">
    <input type="submit" value="Check" id="check">
</form>
```

Пытаюсь выполнить post-запрос в post.php:

```
$data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'query' => $_POST['query']
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $data
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('https://rmsp.nalog.ru/search-proc.json', false, $context);
echo $result;
```

В результате появляется предупреждение:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://rmsp.nalog.ru/search-proc.json):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Пробовал использовать curl:

```
if (isset($_POST['query'])) {$query = $_POST['query'];}
$myCurl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($myCurl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://rmsp.nalog.ru/search-proc.json',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'query='.$query
]);

$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);

echo $response;
```

Получаю следующий ответ:

> {"ERROR":"-","STATUS":500}

Пробовал в php.ini прописывать разное, но не помогло:

> allow_url_fopen=On extension=php_openssl.dll allow_url_include = On

Если просто использовать форму без скрипта, то запрос выполняется:

```
<form method="post" action="https://rmsp.nalog.ru/search-proc.json">
    <input type="text" name="query" id="documentNumber" oninput="identifyType(this.value)">
    <input type="submit" value="Check" id="check">
</form>
```

И в строке браузера тоже работает:

> https://rmsp.nalog.ru/search-proc.json?query=7705151026

В чем может быть проблема?
Мне необходимо в post запросе передать ИНН, введенный в текстовое поле и получить информацию о предприятии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'https://rmsp.nalog.ru/search-proc.json?query=7705151026';
//$url = 'https://rmsp.nalog.ru/search-proc.json';

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "google",
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);

$ch      = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );

var_dump($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['query'])) {$query = $_POST['query'];}

echo file_get_contents('https://rmsp.nalog.ru/search-proc.json?query='.$query)
```

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents(https://rmsp.nalog.ru/search-proc.json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` по-прежнему такое предупреждение